# Implicit derivation in application problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to solve an application problem that says the following:

A country's savings $S$ is defined implicitly in terms of its national income $I$ by the equation

$$S^2+\frac{1}{4}I^2=SI+I$$
Where both $S$ and $I$ are in billions of dollars. Find the marginal propensity to consume when $I=22$ and $S=18$.

To solve it I only have to derive implicitly and replace, but I want to know if I derive **implicitly with respect $I$ correctly, is my doubt.**

Note that this expression can be simplified to the following:

$$I^2 - \left(4S+4\right)I + 4S^2 = 0$$

Considering this simplified expression, we can implicitly differentiate with respect to $I$ as follows:

$$\frac{d}{dI}\left(I^2\right) - \frac{d}{dI}\left(\left(4S+4\right)I\right) + \frac{d}{dI}\left(4S^2\right) = 0$$

In other words,

$$2I - 4I\frac{dS}{dI} - 4S - 4 + 8S\frac{dS}{dI} = 0$$

If we take the values from the statement, that is, $I=22$ and $S=18$, we obtain:

$$2\left(22\right) - 4\left(22\right)\frac{dS}{dI} - 4\left(18\right) - 4 + 8\left(18\right)\frac{dS}{dI} = 0$$

Solving for $\frac{dS}{dI}$, we get:

$$\frac{dS}{dI} = \frac{4}{7}$$

Thus, the marginal propensity to consume is $\frac{4}{7}$.

I'll appreciate it

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JohnDouma  basically whether the procedure is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to rewrite the equation as $[S-$(1/2)$I]^2=I$. The purpose of the question is to derive the marginal propensity to consume which is $(1-dS/dI)$. However, what makes sense to me in the application of implicit function in this setting is given the function $f(S,I)=[S-$(1/2)$I]^2-I$, and a pair $(S^*,I^*)$ such that $f(S^*,I^*)=0$ we can solve $S$ as a function of $I$ for all values around some neighborhood of $S^*$, moreover, the "implicit" function is continuously differentiable in the neighborhood as well (and one can calculate the required derivative $dS/dI$). However, the points $S=18$ and $I=22$ **do not** satisfy the savings-income identity so the question makes no sense to me, either in terms of the math or the economics.
We can verify that with $I^*=22$, $S^*=\sqrt22+11$ satisfies the identity and if my calculations are correct marginal propensity to consume in this case is $0.3933$.

$dC/dI=(1/2)(1-1/[S-$(1/2)$I])$